# How to avoid file is being used by another process in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, file-io

I am trying to check whether file exists or not. if not create and write something into it. The file is getting created but not updating and getting error message says it is being used by another process

Code snippet:

```
Public shared sub MyXml()
  If Not System.IO.File.Exists("configfile.xml") Then
    Dim writer As New System.Xml.XmlTextWriter(fullPath.ToString + "\configfile.xml", Nothing)
  End If

  Dim xmlElement As New XElement("FilePath", ConfigWindow.Datapath.Text)
  System.IO.File.WriteAllText(fullPath + "\configfile.xml", xmlElement.ToString())
end sub()
```

Any suggestions please...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`WriteAllText` will create the file, so you can simply remove the `If` statement:

```
Public Shared Sub MyXml()
  Dim xmlElement As New XElement("FilePath", ConfigWindow.Datapath.Text)
  System.IO.File.WriteAllText(fullPath + "\configfile.xml", xmlElement.ToString())
End Sub
```

The reason the file is locked is that your code creates an `XmlTextWriter` that is not disposed, so it keeps holding on to the file.